# Why we say an SSA when it is Software Statement Assertion in long term?

Tags: vowels

We say obtain **a** Software Statement Assertion but when it is abbreviated as SSA, we say **an** SSA.

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's "a" or "an" depends on the next *sound* of what we *say*. So it's "an SSA" because of how we say the name of the letter S. It doesn't matter that the full form would need "a"; all that matters is the sound of what we actually say.

Comment: So what's the sound you say S follows after the first occurrence?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. When we say SSA, we say the names of the letters. So the thing that matters is the first sound of the name of the letter S. This is a vowel sound, so we say "an" before it: "an SSA".

Comment: "An ess ess ay"

Comment: We need to go by the sound. Yes @Colin